# How to change the formatting to the Brazilian standard of a range slider

Tags: jquery, slider, range, mask

I am using lib nouislider for the slider and wNumb for formatting, but it is becoming in the American standard. I would like to put it in the Brazilian standard mask.

Ex: R$ 1.230,58

The user can either move the range or put the data in the input and it has to be integrated, as in the example below.

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://refreshless.com/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css?v=1460">
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <input title="Formatted number" id="input-format">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.2.0/wNumb.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var sliderFormat = document.getElementById('slider');

        noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
            start: 0,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 10000
            },
            format: wNumb({
                thousand: ',',
                decimals: 2,
                prefix: 'R$ '
            }),

        });


        var inputFormat = document.getElementById('input-format');

        sliderFormat.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            inputFormat.value = values[handle];
            inputFormat.value.replace(".", ",");
        });

        inputFormat.addEventListener('change', function () {
            sliderFormat.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
            inputFormat.value.replace(".", ",");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

https://codepen.io/sauloduarte/pen/OJNOPEN

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in another way using only jquery and inputmask.

```js
$(".range-value").inputmask( 'currency',{"autoUnmask": true,
    radixPoint:",",
    groupSeparator: " ",
    allowMinus: false,
    prefix: 'R$ ',            
    digits: 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    rightAlign: true,
});


$(".input-range").on('input', function(){
    range = $(".input-range").val();

    //convert in number, set locale pt-BR
    var n = new Number($(".input-range").val());
    n.toLocaleString("pt-BR")

    //convert in string, and replace . to ,
    $(".range-value").val(n.toString().replace('.', ","));


    //consoles
    console.log("range: " + $(".input-range").val());
    console.log("campo: " + $(".range-value").val());
});


$(".range-value").on('blur', function(){
    range = $(".range-value").val();

    //remove white spaces and replace , to . and convert in float
    var num = parseFloat(range.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(",", "."));

    $(".input-range").val(num);

  //consoles
  console.log("range: " + $(".input-range").val());
  console.log("campo: " + $(".range-value").val());
});
```

```css
.input-range {
  width:25%;
  height:10px;
  background:#efefef;
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.input-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #419EDA;
}
.input-range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
.input-range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  background: #032B5A;
}

.range-value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #419EDA;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 7px
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .input-range {
    width:65%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.5/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
      <input type="text" class="range-value" value="R$ 1 125,10"></input>
      <input class="input-range" type="range" value="1125.10" step="0.01" min="0" max="10000">  
</div>
```